# seaborn clustermap does not rearrange annotation data

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn to plot a clustermap from a matrix, and I want the values of the matrix to be the annotations of the clustermap. However, while the clustermap rearranges rows and columns of the data matrix to form clusters, it does not do so for the annotation matrix.

Here is my code:

```
data = np.random.rand(10,5)
print (data)

 [[0.62906695 0.41046601 0.04774079 0.98012573 0.79686483]
 [0.1618218  0.70365808 0.53644302 0.68291708 0.95152119]
 [0.901431   0.19378611 0.33176554 0.00219459 0.92936903]
 [0.1575622  0.37749714 0.88975381 0.16945422 0.23790588]
 [0.06837024 0.49287138 0.60866541 0.80563271 0.38924653]
 [0.13671484 0.11410341 0.14604541 0.49899899 0.82850949]
 [0.90237875 0.23954254 0.41614074 0.11811778 0.26017433]
 [0.27881206 0.09321617 0.62520404 0.10796313 0.12266986]
 [0.27606845 0.8479972  0.86467503 0.19660883 0.11909075]
 [0.64211049 0.61860723 0.70426254 0.24465052 0.17614033]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C','D','E']).corr()
df

          A         B         C         D         E
A  1.000000 -0.229103 -0.353145 -0.360782  0.084730
B -0.229103  1.000000  0.498165  0.256117 -0.162689
C -0.353145  0.498165  1.000000 -0.443952 -0.727170
D -0.360782  0.256117 -0.443952  1.000000  0.448025
E  0.084730 -0.162689 -0.727170  0.448025  1.000000


sns.clustermap(data=df, annot=df)
```

[image]

As you can see in the figure, the annotations are the same with the original `df` and the values have not been arranged according to the clusters in the figure.

Is there any way I can do this correctly?

Comment: I think you are messing things up. `data` is a *Rectangular data for clustering*. You can use the parameter `metric` to choose the distance metric to use for the data. See the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html#seaborn.clustermap)

Comment: No, I know about `metric` but it doesn't matter here. I just want the ordering of the annotations on the clustermap be consistent with the map itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are manually setting the annotations, just use

```
sns.clustermap(data=df, annot=True)
```

[image]

Comment: What about if I want to set `annot` to some other dataframe than `df`?

Comment: @sisaman the annots are basically passed to heatmap, so just make sure the dimensions of the map and annots(you can pass numpy arrays also) are same,then it should work no matter whatever you pass with annot=other_df

Comment: consider `annot=df**2` for instance.

Comment: I am with @sisman on this: if you use custom annotations, the annotations are not being re-ordered in the same way that original data is if `annot` is set to True.

Comment: Nvm, [they fixed it](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1752) in a recent release.